# OEM partition of 465 GB in a 1TB disk, too big - how to resize it?

Tags: windows, partitioning, oem, ntfsresize

I just bought a new computer and I installed a windows 8 and I would to install a Windows Server 2012 in another partition in my PC, but there is this **OEM partition** that is occupying half of the computer disk. I didn't want to delete it, but to resize it, if possible, 456 GB is too much in my opinion.

Here is a picture of it:
[image]

Comment: Moving the start of a partition, which is what you’d also need to do, is an error-prone operation. Without looking at the circumstances, I’d simply delete it.

Comment: Many forums I saw they always say something like: "Never delete it", it's quite scary, what would be the consequences ? I saw some people saying I could lost the warranty... That is strange, does it all makes sense ?

Comment: If you don't do it right the partition will be useless anyways, why don't you want to delete it exactly besides you been told it's a bad idea?

Comment: @Ramhound, that is just the reason I am asking it, to get to know what would be the consequences. I already installed Windows Server 2012 on that partition, and everything looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download gparted from http://gparted.org/

boot into it. use it to resize the partition.