# Windows partition management, How to move or delete NTFS OEM partition?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I once had partition table like:

Recovery:EFI System Part: C

Then I installed Ubuntu to dual boot.
Windows 10 update then clobbered Grub (I guess) and Ubuntu install was rendered useless.
Now I just want my disk space back as above Recovery:EFI System Part: C

Somehow this 825MB NTFS Healthy OEM Partition has been moved into place...so now I can't just expand my C: partition to use unallocated space.

Is there anything I can do here?
Windows Disk Mgmt won't let me delete the 825MB partition!

[image]

Comment: You can delete the OEM partition outside of Windows[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1431740/moving-an-oem-partition-on-win-10-to-the-end-pf-the-disk).  You should simply be able to install Ubuntu to the unallocated space.  GPT does not have the same restrictions that MBR has[.](https://superuser.com/questions/852534/oem-partition-of-465-gb-in-a-1tb-disk-too-big-how-to-resize-it)

Comment: @Ramhound Would love to have Ubuntu running but right now but I'm just trying to recover my Windows disk space.

Comment: The partition you are attempting to delete always existed.  You likely had two partitions one for the system and for data originally.  That is typically the OEM partition layout.

Comment: Yes, it must have been always there. Partitions aren't "moved into place". And no matter what the Windows update did, in a UEFI system you can always change the boot order back to Ubuntu (Grub). I suggest you learn a bit more about this things so to avoid misconceptions and doing something you'll later regret.

Comment: @Ramhound I partitioned the disk myself so this is a real mystery. Those 338 and 107Gig partitions used to be one partition I swear! I shrunk the C partition and then used the 107GB for Ubuntu. I'm really quite certain the  ~800MB partition is new.

Answer (score 1):

Running

> reagentc /info

shows that 825MB partition is selected as the recovery partition. I know the partition is new in the last 6 months and it has been suggested a Windows update did this.

Sticking the recovery partition between my system partition and the rest of the disk is a total No-Go. I've never once needed to use Recovery mode anyway.

I deleted the partition by running:

> diskpart
>
> list disk
>
> select disk 0 (As seen in the picture above.)
>
> list partition
>
> select partition 5 (The one indicated by reagentc /info)
>
> gpt attributes=0x8000000000000000 (Unlocks partition for deletion)
>
> delete partition

Then I could head into Disk Management and Expand my C drive to use the rest of the volume like it once was.

Comment: "delete partition override" will spare us from having to set the gpt attribute.